# How do I store values from List<Map<String, Object>> into separate Strings?

Tags: java, string, list

I have a

```
List<Map<String, Object>> assetSubtypeClassification
```

which contains the following values:

```
[{AssetName=HVAC, AssetSubTypeName=AHU, AssetClassificationName=Electric/Heat Recovery, FaultTypeName=No Power}]
```

I am looking to split this map into separate Strings for each heading. What is the best way to do this? Apologies if this is obvious as I am new to this

Comment: what is a heading in you map?

Comment: Define "best way". One method may be the most readable, one method may require the least memory, one method may require the least CPU time, some methods may be backwards compatible to previous versions of Java, etc etc. There is no objectively "best way".

Comment: I am looking to split this map into separate Strings for each `heading`- What is that `heading` - 
What is the best `way` to do this- Can you please share what `way` have you tried.

Comment: What is the resulting String supposed to contain ? Only "name" for each map in your list ? The String key of each Map entry for each Map ? The string key + the call to `toString()` of the corresponding object ? Something else ?

Comment: So for example I want  String assetName = "HVAC", String assetSubTypeName = "Electric/Heat Recovery" etc

Answer (score 0):

You probably? want to create a loop to "read" your Object so:

```
// go through the ArrayList 
    for (Map hashMap : assetSubtypeClassification) {
      // for each hashmap get the key and value
      for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : hashMap.entrySet()) {
          String key = item.getKey();
          String value = item.getValue();
      }
    }
```